# O365 Custom Ribbon Action - Disable button until item selected

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365-apps

I'm trying to only enable my custom ribbon button when an item is selected, but it looks like you can't do JavaScript in O365 from everything that I've read.  Is this true?  Is there no way to enable/disable a button based on the item(s) selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom Page components to do that.  There's an execellent article in DIWUG magazine issue 6 on how to do it. http://www.diwug.nl/DIWUG_SharePoint_eMagazine6.pdf